# Let $f(x)$ be a real value function defined by $f(x)=x^2-2|x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Let $f(x)$ be a real value function defined by $f(x)=x^2-2|x|$. If

$g(x)$$ =  \begin{cases} { \mbox{minimum}: f(t): -2 \le t \le x, x \in [-2,0) \\[2ex] \mbox{maximum} : f(t) : x \le t \le 2, x \in [0,2] } \end{cases}$

I'm not sure how I should plot this. The answer of the plot shows $f(x)$ for $-2$ to $-1$ and $1$ to $2$. It is equal to $-1$ between $-1$ and $0$. And it is equal to $0$ from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Do you know how to plot $f$?

Comment: You have asked 10 questions. If you find any of the answers there useful for you, you could "upvote" or "accept" it as an answer.

Comment: @Jack Yes. $ f $ can be plotted easily. The conditions on g(x) is what that is confusing

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

- Sketch the graph of $f$ on $[-2,0]$ and $[0,2]$;
- Looking at what you sketch above, figure out the expression for $g$ by its definition; If you are confused, try some **examples**: what are $g(-2), g(-1.5),g(-1),g(0),g(1),g(1.5),g(2)$?
- Sketch the graph for $g$.

Here is what the graph of $f$ looks like:

> [image]

Now, **exercise**:

Show that
$$
g(x)=\begin{cases}
f(x),& x\in[-2,-1]\\
-1,&x\in (-1,0)\\
0,& x\in[0,2].
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Just curious, what program you used to plot the graph?

Comment: The online [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+x%5E2-2%7Cx%7C).

Comment: Thats the part I am confused with. What will g(0) be? g(0) will be maximum of f(t) where 0 <= t <= 2. What does this mean? Maximum of f(t) is 0 for x belonging to [0,2]. So does this mean that g(0)=0?

Comment: It means exactly as what it is. Can you find what is the maximum of $f$ on $[0,2]$?

Comment: The maximum of f on [0,2] is 0. Does that mean g(x) on [0,2] = 0?

Comment: That's what the definition of $g$ says, isn't it?

Comment: @Jack So would the plot of g(x) be just = -1 for x on [-2,0] and =0 for x on [0,2]?